# VBA on dynamic connector in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I am just beginner at programming with VBA on Visio. What I am looking to do is to write a code that automatically draws a connector between two shapes.

Searching on internet I was able to find a code that does that :

Public Sub AutoConnect_Example()

```
Dim vsoShape1 As Visio.Shape 
Dim vsoShape2 As Visio.Shape 
Dim vsoConnectorShape As Visio.Shape 

Set vsoShape1 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Decision") 
Set vsoShape2 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Process") 
Set vsoConnectorShape = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Dynamic connector") 

vsoShape1.AutoConnect vsoShape2, visAutoConnectDirRight, vsoConnectorShape
```

End Sub

The only thing I want to do now is to be able to add a text on the connector. Let's say add "SSL" on the connector and if possible change to color of the connector to red.

Does anyone knows what is the formula please ? My objective will be to add it to the code just below.

Hope my English isn't too bad. Thanks all for any help.

Raph

Answer (score 1):

I modify and mix codes from official MS manuals

```
Sub ForRaphael()
' This part of the code contains the declaration of variables: existing shapes and connector
' Code borrowed from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.autoconnect
 Dim vso1DShape As Visio.Shape
 Dim vso2DShape1 As Visio.Shape
 Dim vso2DShape2 As Visio.Shape
 Dim vsoCellGlueFromBegin As Visio.Cell
 Dim vsoCellGlueFromEnd As Visio.Cell
  ' Existing connector
 Set vso1DShape = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Dynamic connector")
  ' Existing Decision shape
 Set vso2DShape1 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Decision")
  ' Existing Process shape.
 Set vso2DShape2 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Process")
' -------
' This part of the code contains gluing the ends of the connector to the existing shapes.
' The idea of this part is borrowed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.cell.gluetopos
' -------
 Set vsoCellGlueFromBegin = vso1DShape.Cells("BeginX")
 Set vsoCellGlueFromEnd = vso1DShape.Cells("EndX")
  'Use the GlueToPos method to glue the begin point of the 1D shape
 'to the top center of the lower 2D shape.
 vsoCellGlueFromBegin.GlueToPos vso2DShape1, 0.5, 1
  'Use the GlueToPos method to glue the endpoint of the 1D shape
 'to the bottom center of the upper 2D shape.
 vsoCellGlueFromEnd.GlueToPos vso2DShape2, 0.5, 0
' =======
' This part of the code is suggested by Surrogate
' =======
vso1DShape.Text = "SSL" ' add text to connector
vso1DShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = 2 ' make connector red
vso1DShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineEndArrow).FormulaU = "1" ' add arrow to end
End Sub
```

Hope this code works at your side :)

---

### About colors

You can use [RGB colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/rgb-function-visioshapesheet) with syntax like
`vso1DShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "RGB(7,4,0)"`
But i prefer built-in colors.
[image: Visio system colors]

---

### About line ends

Visio have [45 built-in line ends](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416) (aka arrows). For arrows you can get its number, but without first 0 (from range 0 to 9).
[image]

For example if you want use **Arrow type 07** and **Arrow type 40** from picture you must need code

```
vso1DShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineBeginArrow).FormulaU = "7"    
vso1DShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineEndArrow).FormulaU = "40"
```

Comment: Thanks that did work. Do you know where can I find a table of the diffrent type of colour please for the FormulaU please ? As well as for the end Arrow please ? Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: Raphael, I add some additional info for my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I want to do now is to be able to add a text on the
> connector. Let's say add "SSL" on the connector and if possible change
> to color of the connector to red.

Raph, try add these lines to your code

```
vsoConnectorShape.Text = "SSL" ' add text to connector
vsoConnectorShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = 2 ' make connector red
vsoConnectorShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineEndArrow).FormulaU = "1" ' add arrow to end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Surrogate ! That did work for me ! Do you by chance know how can I add an arrow going towards vsoSahpe 2 please on the connector ?

Comment: Raph, I add new row to code in my previous answer.

Comment: Hi Surrogate, I've tried all the options you've provided me. Unlucky as I am it doesn't work like I want it to work. The thing is that I have three shapes, vsoShape1 vsoShape2, vsoConnectorShape.

Comment: The autoconnect function connects vsoshape to both the other ones. But when I apply your code, but it adds all the options on the vsoconnectorshape. What I want if that is possible is to add it to the connector between the shapes. I am just a beginner with VBA on Visio. Do you think that is possible to do on VBA Visio ? If the way I did the connection between the shapes is too complicated to add text and color to the connector, do you by chance have an other way to connect the shapes plase ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont try code which from your initially message. Method [AutoConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.autoconnect) create new connector. Did you find this code in this manual ? IMHO, you need to use [GlueTo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Cell.GlueTo)